# Remove first line of a file using perl -pe

Tags: perl, sed

I'm trying to remove the first line of the output file "bss_concurrent_calls.txt" using perl -pe instead of system & sed -i. The server I'm using is solaris 9 (infact it didn't recognize "sed -i")

```
open my $file_in, "<", "/export/home/cassi/4.1-15_HPBX/cfg/LicenseCounters.log" or die($!);

open my $file_out,   '>', 'bss_concurrent_calls.txt' or die $!;

while( <$file_in> ) {
    my @columns = split /\s+/, $_;
    print $file_out "$columns[0]\t$columns[2]\n";

}
system('sed "1d" bss_concurrent_calls.txt');
close $file_in;
close $file_out or die $!;
```

Comment: The better way to call system is with a list of arguments: that avoids having to spawn /bin/sh to invoke the command: `system 'sed', '1d', 'bss_concurrent_calls.txt';`

Comment: Why not simply `tail -n +2 bss_concurrent_calls.txt`?

Answer (score 4):

No need to call sed from Perl here (or anywhere else).

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[0]\t$F[2]\n" unless $. == 1' \ 
    < /export/.../LicenseCounters.log > bss_concurrent_calls.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @choroba's answer, but if you want to keep your program structure:

```
use autodie;
open my $file_in,  '<', '/export/home/cassi/4.1-15_HPBX/cfg/LicenseCounters.log';
open my $file_out, '>', 'bss_concurrent_calls.txt';

my $line1 = <$file_in>;  # read the first line
while (<$file_in>) {
    print $file_out join("\t", (split)[0,2]), "\n";
}

close $file_in;
close $file_out;
```

Comment: Just `scalar <$line_in>` will do. There's no need to declare a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
while( <$file_in> ) {
    next unless $i++;
    my @columns = split /\s+/, $_;
    print $file_out "$columns[0]\t$columns[2]\n";

}
```

Comment: @Oesor...could you kindly explain what the "next unless $i++;" is doing? Thanks.

Comment: It skips the first line. With a global scoped undef `$i`, the first time through the loop `$i++` returns 0, then postincrements `$i` to 1. Since 0 is false, the code goes to the next line. The next times through, it returns positive integers, or true, which means that `next unless true` never triggers the `next`.